# SQL Server CUs vs SPs + CUs?

Tags: sql-server, patching

I recently applied the latest SQL Server CUs (Cumulative updates) for their *current* SPs (Service Packs) on our SQL Servers.  I'm getting the sense that I actually really need to update all of them to the latest SP + CU.  For example, we have a 2014 SP2 server, which now has the latest CU for SP2 (SP2 CU18).  Should I update it to the latest SP + CU (SP3 CU4)?
Thanks,
-Peter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply the latest Service Pack and Cumulative Update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191419/apply-the-latest-service-pack-and-cumulative-update). Not the same version, but general advice is version agnostic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I update it to the latest SP + CU (SP3 CU4)?

When a new SQL Server service pack is released, Microsoft provides only 12 months of full support for the previous service pack.

Support is limited for older SPs:

> For customers on supported products with service pack versions that
>   have left full support, Microsoft offers commercially reasonable
>   support as follows:  Commercially reasonable support incidents will be
>   provided through Microsoft Customer Service and Support and Microsoft
>   managed support offerings (such as Premier Support). If the support
>   incident requires escalation to development for further guidance,
>   requires a nonsecurity update, or requires a security update,
>   customers will be asked to upgrade to a fully supported service pack.

. . .

> Microsoft recommends that you apply the latest Cumulative Update (or
>   one released in the last one year) for the corresponding release. The
>   support team might require you to apply a specific Cumulative Update
>   that addresses a specific problem when troubleshooting an issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17138/service-pack-lifecycle-policy

So cross-referencing the release history [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2936603/sql-server-2014-build-versions), yes you should apply SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU4.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you, David.  Apologies for the redundant post.  My initial searching didn't surface the answer I was looking for.  Apparently, I needed to look a little deeper.